# How to save different cube variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop and in each iteration it creates a cube of data, and I want to use them later in a different for loop. Since they are in a cube form,  can not have them for example like `a(:,j)` for each iteration `j` as I have for a vector.

Is there any way to have them after the end of the loop? How about using `num2str`? so I have for example `a1`, `a2`, ... , can I read them in the next for loop for `j` (for example `a(j=1)` )?

I have something like this:

```
for j=1:n
    Aj = something;
end

for jj=1:n
    do something with Ajj
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you have to go into the 4th dimension :)

```
%# pre-allocate
A = zeros( <size of your cube>, n);

%# generate cubes
for j = 1:n
    A(:,:,:,j) = <your data cube>
end

%# use the data cubes
for j = 1:n
    cube = A(:,:,:,j);
end
```